# How can I make a single curve that approximately represents the curves shown in the figure?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

[enter image description here][1]How can I make a single curve that approximately represents the curves shown in the figure in Python?

I want a single curve that approximates all the curves obtained from bond -slip relation of rebar pullout test from concrete, using the equation as shown in the picture.
t = tmax * (s/smax)**a
where tmax, smax are maximum bond stress and corresponding slip value.
'a' is the value that needs to be derived, that represents the relation between t and s.
The data set consists of other different factors like strength of concrete, rebar diameter and rebar type, but for now I am ignoring all those factors and putting all the data in one basket.

I did the following but it doesnot work.

```
  # No constant for Fc is considered　
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
# load the dataset
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nikesu977/bond_slip_data/main/bond_slip_data.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(url, header=None)
data = dataframe.values
# choose the input and output variables
s, t = data[:, 0], data[:, 1]
# plot input vs output
pyplot.scatter(s, t)
pyplot.show()

# find tmax and smax
tmax = t[np.argmax(t)]
smax = s[np.argmax(t)]
# define the true objective function
def objective(s, a):
 return tmax * (s/smax)**a
# curve fit
popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, s,t)
# summarize the parameter values
a = popt
print('t = %.5f * (s / %.5f) ** %.5f' % (tmax, smax, a))
...
# plot input vs output
pyplot.scatter(s,t)
...
# define a sequence of inputs between the smallest and largest known inputs
s_line = np.arange(min(s), max(s), 1)
print(s_line)
...
# calculate the output for the range
t_line = objective(s_line, a)
...
# create a line plot for the mapping function
pyplot.plot(s_line, t_line, '--', color='red')
```

Comment: Trenton McKinne
Thank you . I have added Bond_slip_data.csv.

Comment: You reference an image, but that image is not included in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could first find a mean value of `t` for each unique value of `s`, and then apply curve_fit.
You could try something like:

```py
s_unique = np.unique(s)
t_mean = []

for s_val in s_unique:
    ind = np.where(s == s_val)
    tm = np.mean(t[ind])
    t_mean.append(tm)
```

And then try your curve_fit on `s_unique` and `t_mean`.